# Convert multiquery to a query using group by and so on

Tags: php, sql, mysql

-schema

```
CREATE TABLE `ratings` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `rating` int(11) NOT NULL default '1',
  `rating_start` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) TYPE=MyISAM
```

-myprogram.php

```
foreach($ids as $id){
  $sql =  "SELECT rating FROM ratings WHERE id = '$id' AND rating_start >= NOW()"; 
  $sql .= "ORDER BY rating_start DESC LIMIT 1;"
  $ret = $db->execute($id);
}
```

Can I teke same date from a Query?

now I have  many queries in foreach

Answer (score 0):

Yeah. I would do `substr(implode(",",$ids),0,-1)` though.  Otherwise you'll have a comma left at the end of your ids.